# A problem on construction of a function

Tags: rolles-theorem

Given that $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, it is to be proved that there exists an  $\xi \in (a,b)$ such that
$$f'(\xi)=\dfrac{2}{a-\xi}\cdot (f(\xi)-f(b)).$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation for how to properly render math here. Please also provide your attemps so we can see how should we help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$F(x)=(x-a)^2(f(x)-f(b)),x\in[a,b].$$
Then $F(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$ and
$$F(a)=F(b)=0.$$
By Rolle's MVT, we know there exists $\xi\in(a,b)$ such that $F'(\xi)=0.$
It is easy to see that
$$F'(x)=2(x-a)(f(x)-f(b))+(x-a)^2f'(x).$$
So
$$F'(\xi)=0\iff f'(\xi)=\dfrac{2}{a-\xi}\cdot (f(\xi-f(b)).$$